# CoffeeScript: Accessing outer class objects from inner class instance

Tags: coffeescript

If there any way to access outer class fields from inner class instance, EXCEPT passing outer class instance to inner class constructor?

To be more specific, I have a simple example:

```
class Test
  constructor: (@number) ->

  class SubTest
    constructor: (@name) ->

    toString: () ->
      console.log @name, @number

  getSubTest: () ->
    return new SubTest "SubTest"

test = new Test 10
test.getSubTest().toString() # SubTest undefined
```

So, I want to get "SubTest 10" instead of "SubTest undefined". Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news! It turns out if you create the closure over `@` yourself, it works just fine:

```
class Test
  self = []
  constructor: (@number) ->
    self = @

  class SubTest
    constructor: (@name) ->

    toString: () ->
      @name + self.number

  getSubTest: () ->
    return new SubTest "SubTest"

test = new Test 10
v = test.getSubTest().toString()

alert v
```

Translates to :

```
var Test, test, v;

Test = (function() {
  var SubTest, self;

  self = [];

  function Test(number) {
    this.number = number;
    self = this;
  }

  SubTest = (function() {

    function SubTest(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    SubTest.prototype.toString = function() {
      return this.name + self.number;
    };

    return SubTest;

  })();

  Test.prototype.getSubTest = function() {
    return new SubTest("SubTest");
  };

  return Test;

})();

test = new Test(10);

v = test.getSubTest().toString();

alert(v);
```

Output:

**SubTest10**

Comment: Well, passing number as an argument to constructor is possible solution, of course, but not the one I need. I would like not to pass any additional arguments to inner class constructor, as I need some universal solution, allowing me to access any of possibly big number of outer class fields. However, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Leaom The problem is the way coffescript encapsulates the inner class off, so I'm afraid this behavior is by design.

Comment: @Leaom See my new edit, I think I found a good workaround for you.

Comment: Oh, that looks great! I think it perfectly solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope an expert like @TrevorBurnham might drop by and offer some further insight or possibly a cleaner solution.

Comment: This is a bullshit solution, it creates a static variable which won't work for multiple parent objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but the accepted answer doesn't work if multiple instances of the outer class are needed (as pointed out by @costa-shapiro). Here is an alternative approach to create the closure with the inner class.

```
SubTest = (test) ->
  class SubTest
    constructor: (@name) ->

    toString: () =>
      console.log @name, test.number

class Test
  constructor: (@number) ->
    @SubTest = SubTest @

  getSubTest: () =>
    return new @SubTest "SubTest"

test = new Test 10
test.getSubTest().toString()
```